# How to send 12 ECG leads data in Generic Health Sensor Service(GHS)

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, ieee-11073

I am working on Generic Health Sensor Service(GHS)defined by BT SIG. I am working on one medical product which has ECG data. I have created the service and all required characteristics for the live stream(GHS) and sent one ECG lead data according to the example in NRF 52840 board which is given in the GHS v1.0 document.
[GHS V1.0 BT SIG example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITD4v.png)

Now my requirement is to send 12 ECG lead data. I have found the information below in an IEEE document.
[ieee standard for 12 lead ECG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQmZ3.png)

According to IEEE 11073-10206-2022 std we can send 12 ECG lead data by using a sample array observation template. My question is how to send these 12 ECG lead data.

Do we need to create separate template for each lead or can we add all ECG lead data into one template.
Because if we create separate templates for each lead the data overhead will be increased.